# Angular validate rule for unique text value

Tags: angular, validation

I got angluar table like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let book of books" [ngClass]="{'isActiveBooks' : !book.isActive}">

        <td>
            <div class="text-description" [appLongText]="book.bookName" ngbTooltip="{{book.bookName}}" [maxTextLength]="45"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" min="1" class="book-order-input"
                placeholder="Enter" (change)="orderChanged=true"
                [(ngModel)]="book.bookOrder"
                >
        </td>       
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to add unqiue validation at `bookOrder` control. So in case if two books have 2 same values, it would show error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the whole list of `books`, and you want to do this validation on the client side, you can define a new validator directive like the following:

```js
@Directive({
    selector:
        '[checkUniqueWithin][ngModel],[checkUniqueWithin][formControl],[checkUniqueWithin][formControlName]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CheckUniqueValidatorDirective, multi: true }],
})
export class CheckUniqueValidatorDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {
    private _validator: ValidatorFn = this._nullValidator;
    private _onChange?: () => void;

    @Input()
    checkUniqueWithin!: Book[];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.checkUniqueWithin) {
            this._createValidator();
            if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
        }
    }

    validate(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return this._enabled() ? this._validator(control) : null;
    }

    registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
        this._onChange = fn;
    }

    private _enabled(): boolean {
        return !!this.checkUniqueWithin;
    }

    private _createValidator(): void {
        this._validator = this._enabled()
            ? this._uniqueValidator(this.checkUniqueWithin)
            : this._nullValidator;
    }

    private _uniqueValidator(source: Book[]): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
            if (source.filter((book) => book.bookOrder === control.value).length > 1) {
                // Return error (i.e. invalid) if there is another book with the same value:
                return { unique: true };
            }
            // Return null (i.e. valid) if there is no book with the same value:
            return null;
        };
    }

    private _nullValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it within the template like the following:

```html
    <input
        type="number"
        min="1"
        class="book-order-input"
        placeholder="Enter"
        (change)="orderChanged = true"
        [(ngModel)]="book.bookOrder"
        [checkUniqueWithin]="books"
    />
```

But if you don't have all the books, then you need to create AsyncValidator instead of normal one, to check the uniqueness on server side, and return the result as an `Observable`.